# Ontology owl and Excel data

Tags: java, rdf, owl, ontology, protege

I am a non programmer. I have a ontology in owl format. I also have an excel sheet (it contains data numeric data with headers of selected ontology). Now I have to connect the excel header with ontology framework and need to extract the links in excel data from the ontology.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post a samples of the data? I'm afraid without that information no one will be willing to help

Comment: I have Institution Ontology
 https://www.isibang.ac.in/~bisu/ontology/instOntology.owl

The excel document of Center data                                                                                                                
Centre BookArticle ConferenceArticle JournalArticle DoctoralThesis.......... etc.
A 1 5 6 7
B 5 36 14 28
C 36 5 47 36
D 25 30 24 12
E 41 34 23 9
F 25 7 40 35
G 5 30 2 20
H 34 5 22 1
I 36 6 7 44
J 4 24 22 27
K 28 9 16 27
L 29 12 47 24

I want to incorporate the data present in excel with the ontology and use some machine learning algorithms.

Comment: I also want to find the relationship with other classes related to the ontology.

Answer (score 4):

Do I understand you correctly that you have an RDF knowledge base whose schema is described by an OWL ontology and you want to import this data from RDF to a spreadsheet?

The most straightforward case to transform RDF to spreadsheets is a SPARQL SELECT query.

## Prerequisites

If you don't already have the data in an application or endpoint where you can query it directly (e.g. Protégé may have a widget for SPARQL queries), there are three prerequisites, else skip those:

**1. Export/Convert the Data**

If you have your data in an application where you can't perform SPARQL queries or as a file in a syntax such as OWL/XML, you need to convert it first, because most SPARQL endpoints don't understand this format, but rather need an RDF serialization such as N-Triples, RDF Turtle or RDF/XML, so you need to export the data in one of those formats.

**2. Setup a SPARQL Endpoint**

Now you can install e.g. a Virtuoso SPARQL endpoint, either locally or on a server or use the endpoint of someone else who gives you access credentials.
It can take a while to install but you can use a Docker image if that is easier.

**3. Upload the Data**

In Virtuoso SPARQL, you can now upload the ontology and the instance data in the conductor under "Linked Data" -> "Quad Store Upload".

## Querying

I don't know of any existing tool that automatically maps ontologies and downloads instances according to a given Excel sheet templates so I recommend to create a [SPARQL SELECT query](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-overview/) manually.

### Example

Let's say your Excel sheet has the header rows "name", "age" and "height" (you said you have numeric data) and the ontology has a person class defined like this in RDF Turtle:

```
:Person a owl:Class;
        rdfs:label "Person"@en.

:age a owl:DatatypeProperty;
  rdfs:label "age"@en;
  rdfs:domain :Person;
  rdfs:range xsd:nonNegativeInteger.

:height a owl:DatatypeProperty;
  rdfs:label "height"@en;
  rdfs:domain :Person;
  rdfs:range xsd:decimal.
```

Now you can write the following SPARQL SELECT query:

```
PREFIX :<http://my.prefix/>
SELECT ?person ?age ?height
{
 ?person a :person;
         :age ?age;
         :height ?height.
}
```

This will generate a result table, which you can obtain in different formats. Choose the CSV spreadsheet format and then you can import it into MS Excel, which solves your problem as far as I interpret it.

Comment: Can you please explain how to install Virtuoso SPARQL endpoint, either locally to use the endpoint

Comment: @dgs: Please refer to the Virtuoso manual at http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS#How%20Do%20I%20Install%20Virtuoso%3F.